# Selenium Hover elements with IE

Tags: java, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8

I have an HTML `div` tag and inside the div there is an element which appears in when mouse enters its boundaries. Now I want to click on the element which becomes visible on mouse entering or hovering.

Issue: the element starts blinking. 
Browser: IE8

I am using the code below

```
   IWebElement we = addToBasket.FindElement(By.Id("MyBox"));
   action.MoveToElement(we).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("plus-icon"))).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Any suggestion why its blinking?

Comment: Which version of selenium you are using ?

Comment: IE11 is still suffering from this problem. Luckily, the solution below still works, too :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The element is blinking because of a feature of the IE driver called "persistent hovers." This feature is of dubious value, but is required because of the brain-dead way IE (the browser, not the driver) [responds to `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/06/whats-wrong-with-internet-explorer.html) when using the `SendMessage` API.

You have a few options. You can turn persistent hovers off by using code like the following:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnablePersistentHover = false;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Be aware, though that this will subject you to the whims of where the physical mouse cursor is on the screen when you attempt to hover. If that's not acceptable, you have a [couple of other approaches](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html) you could take. First, you could turn off so-called "native events," which would cause the driver to rely solely on synthesized JavaScript events. This approach has its own pitfalls, due to relying only on JavaScript to synthesize the mouse events.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Finally, you could migrate from using the default `SendMessage` Windows API to code that uses the more correct `SendInput` API. This is done with the `RequireWindowFocus` property. Its drawback is that the mouse input is injected at a very low level in the system, which requires the IE window to be the foreground window on the system.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

As a final note, do not attempt to set all of these properties at once; pick an approach and stick with it. Several of them are mutually exclusive, and the interaction between them is undefined.

Comment: Thanks Jim. use the above option the blinking stopped. but then I had to physically hover the mouse as you said. I found a solution that was apt for my case. http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver . here they say while running the test keep the mouse course within the boundaries of the browser. doing that blinking stopped and I was able to click on the element.

Comment: As of Selenium 2.47.1, the API has changed. Now it's ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, false);.

Comment: @StephanRauh While you may be correct about the Java language bindings, the .NET ones, to which this question and answer explicitly refer, have not.

Comment: @JimEvans OK. I've added the .NET tag to the question. But I need a peer to review my change - can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevice) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```