# Selenium IE Webdriver Hovering Over Element flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

My code works perfectly fine in FF but if I try with IE it flicker.
Below is my code

```
    WebElement mouseOver= driver.findElement(By.linkText("abc"));
//I'm finding element by linkText. Selenium find the linktext, Next im using Action class to perform the move. 
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(mouseOver).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Once action move to Element line is trigger it seems it goes thru loop or something mouse is keep going over the linkText "abc". Since it flicker its not able to move to next Element. I'm using thread.sleep as there is other items which suppose to display after it hover to the element usually it takes about 1 sec to appear.
I checked following [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) , stated

> The prevailing theory why this occurs is that IE is doing hit-testing
>   of some sort during its event loop, which causes it to respond to the
>   physical mouse position when the physical cursor is within the window
>   bounds.

Is that mean hover will not work in IE. is there any solution to flickering ?

Comment: Unfortunately this known behavior of Internet Explorer

see [this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19662445/1943133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating your Driver you can try this. This worked for me:

```
DesiredCapabilities returnCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
returnCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING, false);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(returnCapabilities);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Flickering stopped but now problem I'm facing it doesn't hover to all elements. My code is basically hover to element "abc" then hoover to element "xyz" then hover to element "EFG' and click on it. now code only hoover mouse to "abc' after that code fails. Do you have any solution? I looked http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver but this solution not working. Example site would be Amazon.com - mouse hover to shop by department, then echo then amazon echo. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have came across the same issue while automating IE test scripts few months back.
the problem seems to be the computer mouse pointer is trying to get the focus while the focus is set to the web element. 
What solved the problem is keep the mouse pointer away from the web page (in the tool bar or on the taskbar).

You can do the this either manually before starting the execution or programmatically using java robot.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(1,1);
```