# Selenium IE11 Mouseover (hover) issue

Tags: selenium, screenshot, internet-explorer-11

My tests use Selenium and Applitools Eyes to take screenshots of the test environment and compare it against the approved baseline. This is to automate visual tests of the application.

When I use IE11 to mouseover, I have attempted using all the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662045/selenium-hover-elements-with-ie), and even though I can get it to mouseover and display the menu, I still have another problem.

When I use the methods listed, the menu will display, and a screenshot is taken of the menu as expected. However, the cursor then REMAINS on the existing menu or the last place the cursor was.

This means if "Menu" is a mouseover menu, I can take a screenshot of the menu, and then click the menu, which is supposed to default me to the "Home" page. However, when I go to the home page, the cursor remains over the "menu" object, which means the mouseover menu pops up and ruins the screenshot for the Home page.

Any suggestions?

As a side note, this code works flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome.